# Pygame: How do I add an image to a rect?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making my own game on Pygame, and I want to add images to rects instead of having a coloured rectangle.

I know how to add an image to pygame, but I want to know if there's some way to add the image and use the Pygame.rect properties such us `rect.centerY` and `rect.centerX`.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: You should use pygame's Sprite class, since it's basically a class that combines an image and a Rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your image, call its [`get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method to get a rect with the size of the image, then set the coordinates of the rect (there are several [attributes](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) like `x, y, topleft, center, etc.`) ...

```
IMAGE = pg.image.load('an_image.png').convert()  # or .convert_alpha()
# Create a rect with the size of the image.
rect = IMAGE.get_rect()
rect.center = (200, 300)
```

... and pass the rect as the `dest` argument to [`pygame.Surface.blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to blit the image at the `rect.topleft` coordinates.

```
screen.blit(IMAGE, rect)
```